# Pre-Processing Images for Pre-Trained Models in Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to use a simple webpage to feed an image to a model I've already trained. When I resize the image and pass it to the model I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) Error: The shape of dict['flatten_input'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,9,9,512], but was [1,300,300,3]"

I'm not sure how to reshape the input to this level - when I trained the model initially I used a pretrained model (VGG19) to process the input, but it doesn't seem like that is available in Tensorflow.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
async function run(){

  const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgcanvas);
  const resized_image =
       tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [300,300]).toFloat();
  const offset = tf.scalar(255.0);
  const normalized = tf.scalar(1.0).sub(resized_image.div(offset));
  const batchedImage = normalized.expandDims(0);
  const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/model.json';
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  const result = model.predict(batchedImage);
  result.print();
}
run();
</script>
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? I had an alternate method where I tried to set up all the convolutional layers first and then tried to pass through the image so it would take on that structure...but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
async function run(){

  const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgcanvas);
  const ModelImage = tf.sequential({
    layers: [tf.layers.conv2d({inputShape=[300, 300, 3], kernelSize: (3,3),
    layers: [tf.layers.conv2d({inputShape: [300, 300, 3], kernelSize: (3,3),
  filters: 64,
  padding: 'same',
  activation: 'relu'}),
  tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 64,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 128,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 128,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 256,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 256,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 256,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
           ]
  })
  const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/model.json';
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  const result = model.predict(ModelImage);
  result.print();
}
run();
</script>
```

Comment: Could you try making predictions on the resized image after expanding the first dimension?

Comment: So something like:  ``` const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgcanvas);
  const resized_image =
        tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [300,300]).toFloat();
  const batchedImage = resized_image.expandDims(0);
  const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/model.json';
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  const result = model.predict(batchedImage); ```

Comment: Yes I do not think you need to normalize the image when passing it to the model.

Comment: I used that structure and still get the same error : Error: The shape of dict['flatten_input'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,9,9,512], but was [1,300,300,3] Still, good to know that that part isn't needed!

Comment: I think that there must be some issue when converting the model to tensorflowjs as the input shape is `[300, 300, 3]` excluding the batch_size from the model. `[-1,9,9,512]` does not make sense. Also could you try removing `.toFloat();` from the resizedImage?

Comment: When I remove .toFloat(); I still get the same error about the [1,300,300,3] shape